# Only Display one view at a time so the user can toggle between the views

Tags: xcode, button, toggle, swiftui, frame

Problem:

I've got 3 separate views I'm displaying all at once but I only want one view showing at a time so the user can just toggle between the three views. Here is what is happening now.

[image: All the views are displayed]

[image: One view is displayed but I can't toggle between the views and have to open all of them together]

The code is long below but if you copy and paste the code into Xcode you can see what is happening now. I have three views that have different size frames. You can click each view button and it will open that view.

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var show1 = false
    @State var show2 = false
    @State var show3 = false

    var body: some View {
                ZStack {
                          NavigationView {
                            VStack {
                                Section {
                                    Color(red: 0.88, green: 0.88, blue: 0.88)
                                    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                                 HStack {

                                    Button(action: {
                                        withAnimation(.spring())
                                        {
                                            self.show1.toggle()
                                        }
                                    }) {
                                        Text("View1")
                                            .font(.headline)
                                            .fontWeight(.regular)
                                            .lineLimit(nil)
                                            .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: -5, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 15))
                                        .foregroundColor(show1 ? .blue : .gray)
                                    }.foregroundColor(show1 ? .blue : .gray)
                                    .padding()


                                    Button(action: {
                                        withAnimation(.spring())
                                        {
                                    self.show2.toggle()
                                    }
                                    }) {
                                            Text("View2")
                                            .font(.headline)
                                            .fontWeight(.regular)
                                            .lineLimit(nil)
                                            .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: -5, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 15))
                                        .foregroundColor(show2 ? .blue : .gray)

                                    }.foregroundColor(show2 ? .blue : .gray)
                                    .padding()


                                    Button(action: {
                                          withAnimation(.spring())
                                          {
                                      self.show3.toggle()
                                      }
                                      }) {
                                        Text("View3")
                                            .font(.headline)
                                            .fontWeight(.regular)
                                            .lineLimit(nil)
                                            .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: -5, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                                        .foregroundColor(show3 ? .blue : .gray)

                                    }.foregroundColor(show3 ? .blue : .gray)
                                .padding()
                                    }}}
                    }
                            VStack (alignment: .center) {
                    if self.show1 {
                        ShowView1().transition(
                            AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .move(edge: .bottom)).combined(with: .opacity))
                            }
                            }

                    VStack (alignment: .center) {
                            if self.show2 {
                                 ShowView2().transition(
                                    AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .move(edge: .bottom)).combined(with: .opacity))
                            }
                    }

                    VStack (alignment: .center) {
                            if self.show3 {
                                 ShowView3().transition(
                                    AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .move(edge: .bottom)).combined(with: .opacity))
                            }
                    }}}}


struct ShowView1: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Color.white
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 52)
            }

        }
    }

struct ShowView2: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack() {
            Color.white
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 600)

            }
        }
    }

struct ShowView3: View {
     var body: some View {
         ZStack() {
             Color.white
                 .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: 300)
             }
         }
     }

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually not switch but toggle each view, so have as a result coexisting views. Here is corrected part of code (only switching logic). Tested with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selectedView: Int? = nil

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            NavigationView {
                VStack {
                    Section {
                        Color(red: 0.88, green: 0.88, blue: 0.88)
                            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity).edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
                        HStack {

                            Button(action: {
                                withAnimation(.spring())
                                {
                                    self.selectedView = 1
                                }
                            }) {
                                Text("View1")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                                    .lineLimit(nil)
                                    .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: -5, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 15))
                                    .foregroundColor(self.selectedView == 1 ? .blue : .gray)
                            }.foregroundColor(self.selectedView == 1 ? .blue : .gray)
                                .padding()


                            Button(action: {
                                withAnimation(.spring())
                                {
                                    self.selectedView = 2
                                }
                            }) {
                                Text("View2")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                                    .lineLimit(nil)
                                    .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: -5, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 15))
                                    .foregroundColor(self.selectedView == 2 ? .blue : .gray)

                            }.foregroundColor(self.selectedView == 2 ? .blue : .gray)
                                .padding()


                            Button(action: {
                                withAnimation(.spring())
                                {
                                    self.selectedView = 3
                                }
                            }) {
                                Text("View3")
                                    .font(.headline)
                                    .fontWeight(.regular)
                                    .lineLimit(nil)
                                    .padding(EdgeInsets.init(top: -5, leading: 15, bottom: 0, trailing: 10))
                                    .foregroundColor(self.selectedView == 3 ? .blue : .gray)

                            }.foregroundColor(self.selectedView == 3 ? .blue : .gray)
                                .padding()
                        }}}
            }
            VStack (alignment: .center) {
                if self.selectedView == 1 {
                    ShowView1().transition(
                        AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .move(edge: .bottom)).combined(with: .opacity))
                }

                if self.selectedView == 2 {
                    ShowView2().transition(
                        AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .move(edge: .bottom)).combined(with: .opacity))
                }

                if self.selectedView == 3 {
                    ShowView3().transition(
                        AnyTransition.move(edge: .bottom).combined(with: .move(edge: .bottom)).combined(with: .opacity))
                }
            }}}}
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like the switching logic is sorted but how would I deselect each view once it is selected?

Comment: @NedBayne-Powell, I would say it is tagged - every view has own tag and selection can be only one, in opposite to code provided in question, where views are toggled so it is possible condition when two or more views are shown (or tried to be shown) simultaneously.

Comment: Thanks fo the help.